# Set resource string to XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I know how to set string from resource 
`<TextBlock x:Uid="Text1"/>`
where `Text1.Text` is "Hello"

But I want to do like this

```
<TextBlock Text = {something here to get GreetingText}/>
```

where `GreetingText` is "Hello"

So that I may get the same string from code also as

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
var string = loader.GetString("GreetingText");
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nikhil's answer is on the right track, but is right for other platforms.

For windows 8, you need to do the following in your resource directory:

```
<x:String x:Key="MyString">This is a resource</x:String>
```

In your xaml:

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource MyString}"/>
```

In code:

```
string myString = (string)(App.Current.Resources["MyString"]);
```

Answer (score 13):

Include this

```
xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Have a resource of `system:string` like this.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="GreetingText">Hello</system:String>        
</Window.Resources>
```

and use it in xaml as

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource GreetingText}" />
```

and use it in code behind as

```
string s = (string)objectofMainWindow.Resources["GreetingText"];
```

Edit: Answer to your comment

Its this way. Resource Dictionary is inside `Window.Resources`

```
<Window 
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

      Your Rest namespaces

     />

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                    xmlns:local="using:ATTFamilyMap.strings">
        <system:String x:Key="GreetingText">Hello</system:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

Your Code

</Window>
```

Comment: You mean to say I have to create a System.string file and put your xml tags in it ???

Comment: This is my resource dictionary and it's giving me some errors. `<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:ATTFamilyMap.strings"
    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Window.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="GreetingText">Hello</system:String>
</Window.Resources>
</ResourceDictionary>`

Comment: Error1 Unknown attachable member 'Window.Resources' on element 'ResourceDictionary'
Error2 Unknown type 'String' in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib'

Comment: Your elements are in the wrong order. Place the ResourceDictionary-element inside the Window.Resources element. Look at Nihkils code-example! :)

Comment: I couldn't get "<system:String" to work with the way Nikhil described for Windows 8, but it did work with as "<x:String" for whatever reason.