# Use DynamicResource as part of Binding's StringFormat

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a TextBlock which displays signal frequence (e. g. 10 Hz):

```
<TextBox Name="Frequency" Text="{Binding Path=Frequency, StringFormat={}{0} Hz}"
```

Now I want to localize "Hz". Ideally would be to just use DynamicResource as part of String.Format:

```
<TextBox Name="Frequency" Text="{Binding Path=Frequency, StringFormat={}{0} {DynamicResource Measure/Hz}}"
```

But it doesn't work. I was also thinking about MultiBinding but looks like there is no easy way to access DynamicResource.

Of cource I can combine Frequence value and Frequence measure in ViewModel and just bind it. But I am curious whether there is a nice UI-only solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MultiBinding with StringFormat {]{0} {1} with the second binding bound to the resource that will contain your 'Hz', that can be stored in a resx file or in your xaml as resource of String type.

[Set resource string to XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890279/set-resource-string-to-xaml)

Comment: But how can I use resource as part of MultiBinding?