# Access .resx string resource within xaml layout in uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'd like to access resources directly in my xaml layout, and official [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965326.aspx) give us some poor examples so I can't get it work. Suppose following `Resources.resw` :

[image]

I can access my string resources from C# class like so:

```
 var loader = new ResourceLoader();
 var resourceString = loader.GetString("txt_ok");
```

How can I access this resource in xaml for a `TextBlock` text for example?

```
<TextBlock
  x:Name="MyTextBox"
  Text="I want to get string resource here"/>
```

I was trying some examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890279/set-resource-string-to-xaml) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919367/get-values-from-resx-files-in-xaml) but no succes

Comment: When you use x:Static as explained in the linked solutions, do you get compilation errors? If so, maybe you need to make your resx public (open properties and set custom tool = PublicResXFileCodeGenerator).

Comment: I get error `Static is not supported in a Windows Universal project.` when try it like: `Text="{x:Static MyAppName.Properties.Resource.txt_ok}"`

Comment: If you (or further readers) are still looking for a solution that can be re-used across other (asp.net/xamarin/wpf) projects and/or only want to use the `Text` property to bind to resources, check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35813707/2901207

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In UWP app, when you define a string resource in your resource file, the `Name` property of this string can be either "Name" or "Name.Property".

In xaml code, we use `Uid` attribute to associate controls to resource, but when we use resource in xaml code, we must add the specified property to the resource's name, in case the control don't know what property should be applied to the string resource.

This is the same in the code behind, you get the resource using

```cs
 var loader = new ResourceLoader();
 var resourceString = loader.GetString("txt_ok");
```

but you still need to set this `resourceString` to the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` for example:

```cs
txt.Text = resourceString;
```

So if you want to use the string resource directly in xaml code, you will need to  edit your resource file like this:

[image]

And you can now associate your `TextBlock` to your resource like this:

```xml
<TextBlock x:Uid="txt_cancel" />
```

Or like this (not 100% correct, it depends on the location of your resource file):

```xml
<TextBlock x:Uid="/Resources/txt_settings" />
```

### Addition: Accessing `Name.Property` from code

If you still want to access those resources in code, just replace the `.`s with `/`s:

```cs
loader.GetString("txt_ok/Text");
```

### Addition: Properties besides text

You can also define other property in your resource file for example like this:

[image]

And when you apply this resource for a `TextBlock`:

```cs
<TextBlock x:Uid="MyApp" />
```

You will see:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Access string resource property in c# code

```
var res = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
var deleteText = res.GetString("DeleteBlock/Text");
var confirmYes = res.GetString("ConfirmYes");
```

https://liftcodeplay.com/2015/11/08/accessing-resource-strings-via-code-in-uwp/